# Where an index applies

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

In my basic understanding of indexes and running of the `explain` statement, it seems that they only apply to `WHERE` and `ORDER BY`. Are there any other places / instances where indexes apply in `SELECT` statements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data in an index may be used if you are only selecting the exact fields that are also used in the index chosen by mysql.

However; Asking this question to me tells me that you miss the fundamental point of indexes and how they work. It may be a good idea to just read a chapter or two from the manual to get a clearer understanding -- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/optimization-indexes.html. It *should* be very logical to you that they are mainly used to fulfill the WHERE and ORDER BY clauses.

Answer (score 3):

You forgot `JOINS`. It became a common practice to design the tables in such way that they'll be joined by FOREIGN KEY constrainted fields (which are indexed 'automatically' - at least, in MySQL). But sometimes exceptions are made - to bite their creators hard later. )

Answer (score 1):

When designing indexes, follow these guidelines:Use indexes on tables with numerous rows, on columns that are used in the WHERE clause of queries or in table joins, and on columns used in ORDER BY and GROUP BY queries.

Avoid infrequently used indexes on frequently updated columns. In addition, avoid having many indexes on a table that is frequently updated. Otherwise, you unnecessarily increase the insert and update times of your queries.

Use clustered and nonclustered indexes appropriately. Understand the purpose of each and choose the correct type for your scenario.

Use a covering index to reduce the query execution time of frequently used statements. A covering index is a nonclustered index that has all the columns that come in a WHERE clause and in the query column selection.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ET0EIxRTTgM